# Cloudsearch range failing for negative integers

Tags: amazon-cloudsearch

I have records in Amazon's cloudsearch that are timestamped with an `int` representing milliseconds since the epoch. I call the field `time`. This can be negative for dates before 1970. When I perform a structured query using `time:[0,}`, it's returning negative as well as positive timestamps, which is wrong. The docs say that ints are 64-bit signed, so I don't see why this wouldn't be valid. My query syntax works fine with other fields that are only positive-valued. Are range searches actually restricted to positive numbers?

(aside: I know I could use a date string format, but I want to use an integer for consistency with other parts of my system. Also I want to be able to represent BCE dates and I'm not sure whether YYYY:MM:DD formats behave safely when YYYY is negative.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Cloudsearch queries work fine with negative numbers, as you'd expect. My problem was that I'd previously defined this field as a `text` field (and a text comparison won't numerically order strings like '123', '-555', '-1', etc.) I'd changed the field to an `int`, but I'd forgotten to re-index, so Cloudsearch was still secretly treating it as `text`.

To re-index after changing field types you can use:

`aws cloudsearch index-documents --domain-name mycloudsearch`

or you can do it from the web interface.